# What is the description of the range of the complex function $f(z)=2z-1$ for $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

As the description says,  I need to find the range. I got the range to simply $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$, but I really am not too sure.  Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct

Comment: And that comes from:

$f(z) = 2x - 1 + i *2y$, and since the domain is restricted to $Im(z)<0$, then the range must be too?

Comment: exactly, whereas the real part $x$ can be chosen arbitrarily indipendentely from the choice of $y$ (since $2x-1$ is surjective as a function on the reals and the two components are orthogonal)

Comment: The geometric picture behind the whole is also quite nice: take the lower half plane, then multiplication by $2$ streches it left and right but doesn't change the shape, and subtracting $1$ just moves the lower half plane to the left, leaving it once more unchanged.